# IF AND statement in MS WORD

Tags: if-statement, ms-word

I need a statement that gives a certain amount depending on the field value:
If x is in the range between 10 and 20 then the answer is 15 if not then it should go to identical statement with a different range.
I cant seem to get the first part working, this is what I got so far:
{=IF(AND(x>10,x<20)"yes","no")}

Comment: This question is very unclear. You don't even tell us what language you are using I would assume VBA, but the { } seem to indicate otherwise. Stating your goal, providing sample input and output as well as more complete code would all be helpful.

Comment: Together the reference to 'field value' and the field braces (i.e. {}) indicate the OP is working with field coding.

Comment: Sorry I did not Specify, this is in MS WORD.
the Goal:
to calculate the minimal amount to pay depending on the debt amount, for example if debt amount is between 100 and 200 minimal amount to pay is 75, if debt amount between 200 and 300 minimal amount to pay is 150 and it goes on like that. in the place of "x" a merge field would be inserted representing current debt.
hope that clarifies it. There is no code, input or output to share, im just trying to figure out how to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really don't need all that circumlocution. For example:

```
{IF«field»> 300 125 {IF«field»> 200 100 {IF«field»> 100 75 0}}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
{=INT((X-1)/10)=1 \# "'Yes';;'No'"}
```

Alternatively:

```
{=AND(Val>10,Val<20) \# "'Yes';;'No'"}
```

To see how to do a wide range of other calculations in Word, check out my **Microsoft Word Field Maths Tutorial**, at:
https://www.msofficeforums.com/word/38720-microsoft-word-field-maths-tutorial.html
or:
http://www.gmayor.com/downloads.htm#Third_party

Comment: Thank you! your Tutorial helped me to figure out the formula, however Im now facing a different problem. this works:

{if{=and(30>15,30<45)}=1 2 3}

but the purpose of this formula is to use a merge field in the place of "30" and when I type in this it sends back !Syntax Error

{if{=and(«field»>15,«field»<45)}=1 2 3} 

IF statement works and sends back a "false" result however AND statement sends back !Syntax Error. 

any ideas for how I can make it work?

Comment: just to add, I have tried using this same field on a simple IF statement and it does work, so there is no problem with the field...

Comment: When using mergefields in formulae, you're liable to get syntax errors in the mailmerge main document. These should resolve in the output document when the merge is executed, however. The formula I posted will work equally well in mailmerges - simply replace the X with the mergefield.

Comment: That is what I assumed as well, however once I upload it into the system, it returns a "false" value even though according to the  «field» value it should be "true".

Comment: is there any possibility to try it out differently? lets say if «field» is in the range of 15-45 ?

Comment: «*once I upload it into the system, it returns a "false" value even though according to the «field» value it should be "true"*» So what is the mergefield returning? «*is there any possibility to try it out differently?*» Yes, but obviously the formula would have to be different. See updated answer for a construct using AND that you might find easier to implement. For mailmerges, once you have the formula working as expected, you might find it useful to wrap the formula field in a QUOTE field so that the formula gets converted to just its result in the output.

Comment: Thank you for all your help I really appreciate that, I have found a different approach to this and I'll just post it here for any future answer seekers. it goes like this: { IF «field» >= 100 { IF «field» <= 199.99 75 { IF «field» >= 200 { IF «field» <=299.99 100 { IF «field».........}}}} 0 }
   The logic here is that if field is greater or equal to 100 then we ask if it is less or equal to 199.99 if so then the answer is 75 if not we ask again if fiels is greater than 200 it goes on like that for quite a while. Good news is that it works!!!